# What is the "BEL" character in Notepad++ and how can I get rid of it in PHP

Tags: php

Good day,

In notepad, I have found out that one processed string gave me a couple of 'BEL' characters after it (see picture below).

[image]

Googling showed me that this "BEL" character stands for 0x07 (alarm). However, I don't recall that I have asked for such an 'alarm' character to be inserted in my decrypt function :

```
function decrypt($encrypted_text, $key, $iv, $bit_check)
{
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES,'','cbc','');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cipher,base64_decode($encrypted_text));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
    $last_char=substr($decrypted,-1);
    for($i=0;$i<$bit_check-1; $i++){
        if(chr($i)==$last_char)
        {           
            $decrypted=substr($decrypted,0,strlen($decrypted)-$i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Question: do I have a means in PHP to get rid of this 'BEL' characters?

I hope this question will somehow be useful for the stackoverflow community.

Many thanks for your help and your support.

Comment: It's literally a "Bell"; a character that should trigger a bell sound through the computer speakers

Comment: OK, Thanks Mark. Do you know by chance what I should do to get rid of them? I don't really want to play an ugly bell sound on my computer speaker :)

Comment: I'd guess that either it was part of the encrypted data, or that your decryprt hasn't worked correctly

Comment: I don't think that is really a sound to play. I've got this character in a word document between `1.` and `text`. It's like a gap.